# shut off screen using pygame

Tags: tkinter, pygame

I'm using pygame to build a mockup of a home automation touch screen application.  I would like the screen to shut off if the touch screen has been inactive for a certain period (~5 min), all the while the program continues to update the screen.

Is there anything built into pygame to allow this?

Would tkinter have been a better choice?

Comment: do you mean `computer screen` or `program screen` ? PyGame and tkinter don't have method to shut off computer screen. And probably other GUI frameworks also don't have it. All of them may have to run system command for this. Using Google I found [turn off screen](https://github.com/arjun024/turn-off-screen/blob/master/turnoff.py)

Comment: if program run fullscreen window then it could be simpler to fill window with black color and stop drawing - but you can still make all needed calculation to draw current content when you wake up screen. In PyGame you could simply first draw all on `Surface()` and later draw this surface in window - and when you want shut off then you can still draw all objects on this surface but not draw this surface in window. In tkinter it could be problem - maybe you could create black `Canvas()` and display on top of window.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code that works for me.

I used `pip3 install python3-xlib` to install Python xlib.  Then the following code was useful.

The only remain thing to do, I need to find a way to trigger it after a period of inactivity.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-

import time
import subprocess
from Xlib import X
from Xlib.display import Display
display = Display(':0')
root = display.screen().root
root.grab_pointer(True,
       X.ButtonPressMask | X.ButtonReleaseMask | X.PointerMotionMask,
       X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, 0, 0, X.CurrentTime)
root.grab_keyboard(True,
       X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, X.CurrentTime)
subprocess.call('xset dpms force off'.split())

p = subprocess.Popen('xset dpms force off'.split())
time.sleep(1)
while True:
   print (display.next_event())
   p.terminate()
   break
```

Answer (score 0):

When you aren't running  within X you can use [vgencmd](https://pypi.org/project/vcgencmd/):

```
from vcgencmd import Vcgencmd
vcgm = Vcgencmd() 

vcgm.display_power_off(0) # Display off
vcgm.display_power_on(0)  # Display on
```